# PHP concatenate values into array

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

I'm new to php and would like to know how to make the following possible ...

Below I have several arrays populated from Database rows. Id like to have a new array `mappingId` that concatenates several rows to form the value for the `mappingId` array. Below I have used array_combine but this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone advise on what to use?

```
$appId = array();
$appDate = array();
$appTime = array();
$appDoctorId = array();
$mappingId = array(); // combined values

for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($resultAppointmentsBooked); $i++)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultAppointmentsBooked);
    $appId = $row[0];
    $ids[] = $row[0];
    $appTime[] = $row[3];
    $appDate[] = $row[4];
    $appDoctorId[] = $row[2];
    $mappingId = array_combine($row[4], $row[3], $row[2]);

    //Test output
    echo "MappingId: $row[4]$row[3]$row[2] <br />";
    echo "MappingId2: - $mappingId[$i] <br />";
}
```

I have also used 'array_merge' the following way ...

```
                $ids[] = $row[0];
                $appTime[] = $row[3];
                $appDate[] = $row[4];
                $appDoctorId[] = $row[2];

                $mappingId = array_merge($appDate, $appTime, $appDoctorId);
```

but when I print the values ...

```
             echo "MappingId2: $mappingId[$i] <br />";
```

It only output the value of the first array.

Comment: How should `$mappingId` hold the data?

Comment: What data you are getting `$resultAppointmentsBooked` and how you want to structure `$mappingId`?

Comment: Just a nitpick, concatenation is a string operation, so you cannot concatenate values into an array. And array_combine wants two arrays as parameters (one for keys and one for values), so passing strings will not work.

Comment: I want 'MappingId' to told the value of appDate+appTime+appDoctorId. $resultAppointmentsBooked essentially rows from a database table. @deepakb @e

Comment: what does `appDate+appTime+appDoctorId` mean? Do you want those value with a `+` sign or something like this `appDate apTime appDoctorId`?  Please let me know. Check my answer!

Comment: @deepakb I just want the values of those arrays concatenating into one, for example, 'MappingsIds' should print 20151202-910-1

Comment: check my answer @CottonSocksBro

Comment: @deepakb Answer seem's to do the Job!!!

Comment: OK, great! Accept it if you got your answer! @CottonSocksBro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. If this is what you need. Here in the below codes 
`$mappingId` contains array of individual `appDate`, `appTime`, `appDoctorId` in array format. If you don't want array just want concatenate those value with one element then also you can do that. Please let me know!

```
$mappingId = array(); // combined values

for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($resultAppointmentsBooked); $i++)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultAppointmentsBooked);
    $appId = $row[0];
    $appTime = $row[3];
    $appDate = $row[4];
    $appDoctorId = $row[2];
    $myArr = array();
    //array_push($myArr, $appDate, $appTime, $appDoctorId);
    // If you want in concatenate format
    array_push($myArr, $appDate."".$appTime."".$appDoctorId);
    array_push($mappingId, $myArr);
}
```

Comment: Array-push seem to do the job!

Answer (score 1):

You can add values to an array by doing this:

```
 $mappingId[] = 'Hello';
 $mappingId[] = 'There';
 $mappingId[] = 'Friend';
```

Results in:

```
 $mappingId = array('Hello', 'There', 'Friend');
```

--

You can also use `array_merge`.

This merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php)

```
array_merge(array(1), array(2,3)); //return array(1,2,3)
```

Comment: Please provide a code example to further explain your answer. Also *why* `array_merge`.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this , array_merge should work:

```
$ids = $row[0];
$appTime = $row[3];
$appDate = $row[4];
$appDoctorId = $row[2];
$mappingId = array_merge($ids, $appTime, $appDate, $appDoctorId);

echo "MappingId: $row[4]$row[3]$row[2] <br />";
echo "MappingId2: - $mappingId <br />";
```

Comment: Hi there, I've tried this and it results is no output. @david